# Viewing ForiegnKey data in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, foreign-keys

I want to create a view that displays data from a foreignkey in Django.

I have some barbers that are available on certain dates and I want to see which dates a barber is available on. Later I need to know which barbers are available on which dates.

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import time

class Barber(models.Model):

    BARBERS = (
        ('KK', 'Kim Kardashian'),
        ('CJ', 'Caitlin Jenner'),
        ('KW', 'Kanye West')
    )

    LOCATION = (
        ('CL', 'Central Detroit'),
        ('NL', 'North Detroit'),
        ('SL', 'South Detroit'),
        ('EL', 'East Detroit'),
        ('WL', 'West Detroit'),
    )

    name = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=BARBERS)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=LOCATION)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Date(models.Model):

    date = models.DateField()
    name = models.ForeignKey(Barber, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

urls.py in my app

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import schedule, appointments

urlpatterns = [
    path('', schedule, name='schedule'),
    path('/appointments/<int:id>/', appointments, name='appointments')
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import Barber, Date

def schedule(request):
    barber = Barber.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'schedule.html', {'barber': barber})

def appointments(request, name):
    dates = Date.objects.filter(name=name)
    return render(request, 'appointments.html', {'date': dates})
```

appointments.html

```
<h1>Appointments</h1>

<ul>
  {% for date in dates %}
    <li> {{ date.name }} {{ date.dates }} </li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

schedule.html:

```
<h1>Schedule</h1>

<ul>
  {% for barb in barber %}
    <a href="{% url 'appointments' Barber.id %}">
    <li> {{ barb.name }} {{ barb.location }} </li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

The error I get is:

```
Reverse for 'appointments' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['\\/appointments\\/(?P<id>[0-9]+)\\/$']
```

Comment: The error is caused by the `url` template tag.  Can you check whether you have `{% url 'appointments' %}` in your template? You need to pass an id in your `url` tag for appointments.

Comment: somewhere in your template, you miss the `id`

Comment: I'm passing <a href="{% url 'appointments' Barber.id %}"> in a separate html template that should link to appointments.html

Comment: Then you need to show that template, and the view that renders it. There's no point only showing unrelated code.

Comment: `appointments` is waiting for an `id(int)`, whereas you put `name` as argument in your view...

Comment: how do I tell it to filter by the id of the record in the primary table and apply that to the foreign table?

Comment: this `{% url 'appointments' Barber.id %}` should be `{% url 'appointments' barb.id %}`.. hovewer you will still get another issue  in your view `appointments(request,name)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe your code should be:

```
{% for barb in barber %}
    <a href="{% url 'appointments' bard.id %}">
    <li> {{ barb.name }} {{ barb.location }} </li>
{% endfor %}
```

views

```
def appointments(request, id):
    barb = Barber.objects.get(id=id)
    dates = barb.date_set.all()
    return render(request, 'appointments.html', {'dates': dates})
```

Comment: Although I can't imagine OP won't need the actual Barber object on the page dedicated to the appointments for that barber; probably better to send that to the context and do the `date_set.all` in the template itself.

Comment: This makes the link work but I'm not seeing any dates on my appointments page?

Comment: my mistake: the context should be `{'dates':dates}` in the last line.. `date` with `s`

Comment: @DanielRoseman you're right, but I wanted to explain the logic clearly based on his code